# How to create variable with the first day of current month in Databricks Spark Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, databricks, java-time

Using Spark Scala on Databricks, I am trying to create a variable that contains the first day of the current month.

In the first step, I just get the current date, and it works fine:

```
val current_date = LocalDate.now()
```

That gives me the correct output, such as:

```
current_date: java.time.LocalDate = 2022-05-02
```

My problem is when I try to get the first day of the current month. I have tried to use [TemporalAdjuster](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstDayOfMonth--), but it doesn't work. Can anyone indicate me the correct way to do this?

Examples that I have tried:

```
val current_month = current_date.temporal(TemporalAdjuster.firstDayOfMonth())

>>> error: value temporal is not a member of java.time.LocalDate
val current_month = current_date.temporal(TemporalAdjuster.firstDayOfMonth())

>>> error: value firstDayOfMonth is not a member of object java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster
val current_month = current_date.temporal(TemporalAdjuster.firstDayOfMonth())
```

```
val current_month = current_date.with(TemporalAdjuster.firstDayOfMonth())

>>> error: identifier expected but 'with' found.
       val current_month = current_date.with(TemporalAdjuster.firstDayOfMonth())
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use the method `withDayOfMonth(1)`. The `1` inside the brackets indicates that it must return the first day of month.

The following code works:

`val current_month = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use `date_trunc` function to round a current date to a given granularity. To get first day, you need to truncate current date to a month level, like this (we need to use `to_date` because `date_trunc` returns a timestamp):

```scala
to_date(date_trunc( "mon", current_date()))
```

For example, if you run it as following on Databricks:

```scala
display(spark.range(3).withColumn("first_day", 
  to_date(date_trunc( "mon", current_date()))))
```

you'll get

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alex! Thanks a lot for the answer! I see that your solution works. However, I would like to create as an independent variable and not as the values in a column. My reason is that, in the specific case I am working on, I use it as a parameter in several parts of my code (as filters, for example). If I use your solution, I would have to either do multiple joins or create multiple times the "first_day" column. That is why I was trying to work with java.time.LocalDate. Again, thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I was confused by Spark in your question. Otherwise its just a Scala question, not Spark specific

Comment: Hi Alex! I just found how to do it and it was simpler than I thought. I just had to do ```LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1)```. Thanks for trying to help!!